# Issues Running a Lambda Function Attached to a VPC with aws-controltower-AuditAdministratorRole

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

My organization requires all Lambda functions to be attached to a VPC and Lambda functions attached to VPCs must run under a role that has been assigned the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole policy.  However, my Lambda must run under the aws-controltower-AuditAdministratorRole, which has the AWSLambdaExecute policy assigned to it, but not AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.  Also, an SCP prevents you from editing the aws-controltower-AuditAdministratorRole, so I'm not sure what to do.  Does anyone have experience running a VPC-attached Lambda with the aws-controltower-AuditAdministratorRole?  If so, how did you get it to work?

I considered creating a new role that has rights to assume the aws-controltower-AuditAdministratorRole, however, this would also invole editing the aws-controltower-AuditAdministratorRole.